# Why is my terminal saying "permission denied" when I try to clone?

Tags: git, github

Anything I try to clone from github, but my terminal blocks me with the message "Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository". What do I need to do to clone to my desktop files?

Comment: You need to upload your public key onto github, and then make sure you use your private key when trying to clone if you're cloning from an `ssh` URL.

Comment: Sounds to me like you need to check your SSH setup - see [the GitHub docs on the subject](https://help.github.com/articles/which-remote-url-should-i-use/#cloning-with-ssh-urls)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comments to your question are likely correct - you are missing a public key.

I suggest navigating to the github www page for the repository that you want to clone, and change from `SSH` to `HTTPS` and use that clone url instead.  It should be in the following form:

```
https://github.com/{username}/{project}.git
```

You can also just try the new URL without the need to navigate the github www UI by using the format described above, rather than the ssh form ( `git@github.com:{username}/{project}.git` )

Comment: My answer allows the user to clone the repository *without* ssh keys.  If it's a private repository, the user will be prompted for username / password

Comment: Thank You! That was perfect!

Comment: Okay, I got it! yeah, it says you need 15 rep points before you can upvote. I'm new to this thing. :)

Answer (score 0):

You should check step 4 on this help article, https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys/#step-4-add-your-ssh-key-to-your-account